# Unable to import required dependencies, Python with Pandas and Numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, dependencies, command, line

I think this question has been asked before on the internet, but the proposed solutions have so far not worked.

I am trying to run a script that imports numpy and pandas. When I run using the Python Console in my IDE (PyCharm), everything works fine. However, when I run the script from the command line, the following error is displayed:

```
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

and

```
Unable to import required dependencies
```

I am using Anaconda Navigator. There my Pandas and Numpy are listed. I tried to uninstall them via the conda shell (conda uninstall numpy, conda uninstall pandas) and then install them again, but without result.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: The environment was already activated, so this was not the problem. I solved the problem in a different way, though. Will post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I de-installed Anaconda and installed pip instead. Then I installed the modules using pip, and it worked like a charm.

(Not the most elegant answer since it does not explain why things went wrong in the first place, but it offered a workable solution at least.)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already call this (no quotes)

```
conda activate "name of environment that has your modules installed"
```